# Adding an Owl component to an existing view in Odoo 16

Tags: odoo, odoo-16, odoo-owl

I have an existing Odoo 16 application with a working view that contains the following inside a Form view:

```xml
    <sheet>
        <notebook>
            <page name="plan_vehicles" string="Vehicles">
                <field name="vehicle_time_ids"/>
            </page>
        </notebook>
    </sheet>
```

I want to add another page to the notebook that will display an Owl component.
I have tried to extract the required code from the official tutorial, so I have the following code:

`templates.xml`:

```xml
    <odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="transport.stops" name="Awesome T-Shirt thank you">
            <html>
                <head>
                    <t t-call-assets="transport.assets"/>
                </head>

                <body>
                </body>
            </html>
          </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

`main.js`:

```js
    /** @odoo-module **/
    
    import { browser } from "@web/core/browser/browser";
    import { mount } from "@odoo/owl";
    import { Stops } from "./stops";
    
    // The following code ensures that owl mount the component when ready.
    // `templates` contains templates contained in the bundles.
    //
    // In the mount options, it's also possible to add other interresting
    // configuration: https://github.com/odoo/owl/blob/master/doc/reference/app.md#configuration
    import { templates } from "@web/core/assets";
    owl.whenReady( () => {
        mount(Stops, document.body, { templates, dev: true });
    });
```

`stops.js`:

```js
    /** @odoo-module **/
    
    import { Component, useState } from "@odoo/owl";
    
    export class Stops extends Component {
        static template = "transport.stops";
    }
```

`stops.xml`:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <templates xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-name="transport.stops" owl="1">
            <div class="p-3">
                hello world
            </div>
        </t>
    </templates>
```

`manifest.py`:

```py
    'assets': {
            'web.assets_backend': [
                'transport/static/src/*.**',
            ],
            'web.assets_qweb': [
                'transport/static/src/*.xml'
            ],
            'transport.assets': [
                # bootstrap
                ('include', 'web._assets_helpers'),
                'web/static/src/scss/pre_variables.scss',
                'web/static/lib/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss',
                ('include', 'web._assets_bootstrap'),
    
                'web/static/src/libs/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css', # required for fa icons
                'web/static/src/legacy/js/promise_extension.js', # required by boot.js
                'web/static/src/boot.js', # odoo module system
                'web/static/src/env.js', # required for services
                'web/static/src/session.js', # expose __session_info__ containing server information
                'web/static/lib/owl/owl.js', # owl library
                'web/static/lib/owl/odoo_module.js', # to be able to import "@odoo/owl"
                'web/static/src/core/utils/functions.js',
                'web/static/src/core/browser/browser.js',
                'web/static/src/core/registry.js',
                'web/static/src/core/assets.js',
                'transport/static/src/**/*',
            ],
        },
```

- the import of the `template.xml` file in the `data` list.

I think I am missing two things:

- how does the Owl template `stops.xml` relate to the template in `templates.xml` and
- how to add the the component/template to a new page in my notebook so that I can see the 'hello world'.

Answer (score 2):

What I was missing was to register the component. At the ent of the javascript field I added this line:

`registry.category("fields").add("stops",Stops)`

I could then add the component to my view like this:

```
<field name="trip_summary" widget="stops"/>
```